# What is the best practice to create a unique url for every user profile

Tags: unique, user-profile

In my every application i want to create a unique url for users profile as http://app.com/username .

I have the name of user is : 'Vijay Kumbhar' i can create http://app.com/vijay_kumbhar, but if there is another user registers with the same name then what will be better way of creating url for that user. 
 one way is to add vijay_kumbhar_1, but i dont think this is the proper way of creating a unique url

Can you please suggest me the better way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping in the User experience in consideration, firstly provide the user with unique id, through which you can identify the User easily. After that you can allow the User to opt for any new User Name (screen name), but there should be a check again that the user name has to be unique again. Depends upon your requirement. Do keep us posted what way you opted at last.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same approach as stackoverflow using

stackoverflow.com/users/unique-number/user-name

Answer (score 1):

Usually user names must be unique. If you're using login in the URL, then they urls will be unique. It is common thing to prevent registering two users with the same login.

EDIT:
If you'd like to keep usernames not showing (e.g. for some security reasons), you can use in URL hashes from users logins, not the logins e.g.
app.com/mylogin > app.com/123123123

Answer (score 0):

You keep your registered users most likely in some kind of a database. In SQL it is natural that every row has a unique ID. You could use such an ID as a part of the url, instead of an own running number for every name combination.

Answer (score 0):

**You definitely need to make sure you do NOT show the actual "username" in the URL if you have a publicly accessible URL.**

If you use an ID number, just remember to avoid the error that Wordpress made - creating the user IDs sequentially, starting with the default admin user as "1".

That made it easy for hackers to query with something like

> example.com/profile?author=1

That would return

> example.com/admimuser

And show him the actual username of the admin... and then cracker starts pounding away trying to brute force the admin username's password.

And never show the login name to anyone or in any URL other than to the user or admins!