# How Do I create UNIQUE url for each profile

Tags: reactjs

How do I create a unique URL for Each Profile I have ABSOLUTELY No Idea What to do Here If I want to make a unique URL literally ANYTHING but It should be like `localhost:3000/Profile/The-url` and it should be totally random it SHOULD not be same I know It is not an error but I have NO Idea What do here. I am using React, and I have a database setup in Firebase it is the Firestore database If you WANT anything any questions this question please please give me details because I have No Idea what to do.

I tries to use `useParams()` *sorry if spelling mistake* and I also Tried to search in the web I definitely found some help but I didn't find exactly what do

All the research I have:

[StackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431930/what-is-the-best-practice-to-create-a-unique-url-for-every-user-profile)
[JotForm](https://www.jotform.com/answers/2470322-generate-unique-link-for-each-individual)
[Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-assign-unique-URLs-to-each-user)
[stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104829/what-can-be-used-to-create-a-unique-url-for-a-users-public-page)
[stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182132/unique-url-for-pagination-pages-in-react)

This is all That I found Helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is few ideas :

you can create urls like this `localhost:3000/profile/profile-id` profile id may be guid or insert id of database.

Comment: can you please explain guid or insert ID and can you give a snippet of code, for that?

Comment: and how to get insert id of the database

Comment: guid is 128-bit number used to uniquely identify objects you can create and save when you creating user,I mention primary key of your database entry as insert id

Comment: Just One thing more like If I want `<Link to="/Profile/id" className="ml-1 mt-4 no-underline text-black">` to got to the `id` so How do I get the id? If got then How Should I store it?